# Injectivity and surjectivity of function

Tags: functions

For $f : \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb Z$ with $f(n_1,n_2)= n_1−n_2$ , determine if it is surjective and/or injective.

This is what I have done:
$f: \mathbb N \times \mathbb N \to \mathbb Z$ is surjective if for all $y$ in $Y$, there are $n_1$ and $n_2$ in $\mathbb N$ such that $f(n_1,n_2)=y$.

**Proof:**

$f(n_1,n_2)= n_1-n_2$

$y=n_1-n_2$

$n_1=y+n_2$ and $n_2=n_1-y$

Answer (score 1):

To prove surjection:

$$f(1,1)=0$$
Suppose $y>0$:

$$f(1+y,1)=y$$

Suppose $y<0$,

$$f(1,1-y)=y$$

To check whether it is an injection,  try to  evaluate $f(2,2)$.

Remark about your attempt:

you should pick your $n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ explictly.

Answer (score 0):

$n_1=k_1+a $ , $n_2=k_1 \in \mathbb{N}$

$f(n_1,n_2)=n_1-n_2=k_1+a-k_1=a  $

But

$a=k_2+a-k_2 = m_1-m_2=f(m_1,m_2) \in \mathbb{Z}$, where $m_1=k_2+a,m_2=k_2 \in \mathbb{N}$

$f(n_1,n_2)= f(m_1,m_2)$, $n_1 \ne m_1, n_2 \ne m_2$

-->Not a bijection